# Difference in Outcome While Applying the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I am currently writing some code to control a model train layout. As part of this, how much the distance travelled by a locomotive (under a constant speed) varies during a specific time interval is of interest. During the work done so far, I've used a speedometer to measure the performance of one such locomotive, when running at a specified speed step from the controller. This device measures the average speed (in cm/s) over a short timespan and sends it to a computer. I've thus collected approximately 15,000 values. A short sample of this: 6.98, 7.26, 6.93, 6.57, 7.16, 7.01, 6.99, 8.45,.... The distribution of these values resembles very well a normal distribution, and it was somehow to be expected.
Next the mean (7.026) and standard deviation (0.418) are computed. Now based on the central limit theorem we know that the sampling distribution of the sample mean will approximate a normal distribution for a large number of values, that the mean of this sampling distribution will be the same as the mean of the initial population of individual speed values, and that the variance - for a set of N individual speed values averaged - will be the initial variance divided by N.

Now I'd like to estimate the distance that is going to be covered by the locomotive - by having in mind a model that involves summing up the distances equivalent to the speed values over the initial short timespans.

For a set of N consecutive speed values, we can say that there's a 99.7% chance of the sample mean of these individual speed values to be located between the mean minus 3 x standard_deviation/sqrt(N) and the mean plus 3 x standard_deviation/sqrt(N).

Let's first consider an interval of time equal to 100 timespans - the same timespans that separated each initially collected speed value. Using the numerical values this translates to 6.9 <= sample mean <= 7.151, with a chance of 99.7%. By multiplying the inequation above by 100, we get 690 <= 100 x sample mean <= 715.1. Or in other words I expect - with a 99.7 accuracy - that the distance covered to vary by 25.1 cm during those cummulated 100 timespans.

Let's now move to an interval of time that equals 200 timespans. This time the inequation becomes 6.93 <= sample mean <= 7.11. Multiplying by 200 yields 1386 <= 200 x sample mean <= 1422. This time the distance is expected to vary by 36 cm during these cummulated 200 timespans.

However if we take the inequation for the case where N=100 and simply multiply by 2, this would imply that the distance covered can vary by 50.2 cm (2 x 25.1 cm), quite different that what was found in the last paragraph.

My question is why are different outcomes seen for the N=200 case ?

Or consider the individual speed values - we know with a 99.7% confidence that each and every one is contained between the mean and +/- 3 standard deviations. However multiplying this by 200, and saying that the difference in distance covered is 200 x 6 standard deviations (which adds up to 501.6 cm !) clearly doesn't feel right. It's just I don't have a rigorous explanation.